# Not able to generate same output image from source input

Tags: java, image, awt

I am reading a .jpg file as integer array(source) and trying a generate a new image from same data, but the code is producing a black image. But it should produce the duplicate image as source.

```
        String srcName = "input.jpg";
        File srcFile = new File(srcName);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(srcFile);
        System.out.println("Source image: " + srcName);


        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        int[] src = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);

        System.out.println("Array size is " + src.length);


        BufferedImage dstImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        // generating destination image with same source array
        dstImage.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, src, 0, w);

        String dstName = "output.jpg";
        File dstFile = new File(dstName);
        ImageIO.write(dstImage, "jpg", dstFile);
        System.out.println("Output image: " + dstName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same color encoding type for both images.
It is likely that your input image is not encoded as `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

This fixed it for my test image, which had the type `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`:

```
BufferedImage dstImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, image.getType());
```

However, I wouldn't expect the newly written image to be exactly the same as the input. I'd rather expect ImageIO to introduce some artifacts while encoding the image data to jpg.